# python Search a string in a column, and return another column value from that same row

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am currently trying to write a script that will evaluate a spreadsheet to search column A for a string, and then once it finds that string, print the value of column I in the same row. So far I have the following code but it isn't getting me very far.

any help will be appreciated.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("2016_SF.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb["161226-161228"]
last_r=70
search_str = raw_input("What plant are you looking for? > ")
last_r = cell.row


def FindXlCell(search_str,last_r):
    for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=last_r):
        for cell in row:
            if (search_str == cell.value):
                print(search_str, last_r, cell.row,)
```

Comment: What do you mean "isn't getting you very far"? Code looks okay.

Comment: Charlie, it wont print the information I want and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: If it's not printing anything then it's not finding anything. Move your print statement outside the `if` so you can see which cells are being looked. It could simply be `offset` I've never really understood how that was supposed to work which is why I'm removing it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: search column A for a string, and then once it finds that string, print the value of column I in the same row
>
> **Note**: As my 'text.xlsx' uses Column 'C' with "keyX" and doesn't have a Column 'I', I use 'C' and 'D' instead of 'A' and 'I' as requested.

Worksheet in test.xlsx:
[image]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def FindXlCell(search_str, range=None):
    """
    Iterate over a given 'range' match 'cell.value' with 'search_str'

    :param search_str: String to find
    :param range: Range to iterate, defaults to whole sheet
    :return: 'None' if no match else 
              all cells from the matching Row as 'list of cell objects'
    """
    global ws
    
    if not range:
        range = ws.iter_rows() # Defaults to whole sheet

    for tupleOfCells in range:
        for cell in tupleOfCells:
            if (cell.value == search_str):
                return [_tuple[0] for _tuple in ws.iter_cols(min_row=cell.row, max_row=cell.row)]

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# search_str = raw_input("What plant are you looking for? > ")
search_str = "key2"

# Search only Column 'C' == 3, openpyxl is 1-based
cellsOfFoundRow = FindXlCell(search_str, ws.iter_rows(min_col=3, max_col=3))

if cellsOfFoundRow:
    # List cellsOfFoundRow is 0-based, Index of D == 3
    print("Found:{}, the value of Column D is {}"
          .format(" ".join([cell.value for cell in cellsOfFoundRow]),
                  cellsOfFoundRow[3].value))
else:
    print("Could not find '{}' in the given cell range!".format(search_str))
```

> **Qutput**:
>
> Found:A3 B3 key2 200, the value of Column D is 200

---

**Usage with other range examples**:

Search the whole sheet

```
cellsOfFoundRow = FindXlCell(search_str)
```

Starting with Row 2 and match **only** on Column 3 == 'C':

```
cellsOfFoundRow = FindXlCell(search_str, ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=3, max_col=3))
```

Limit the Range from Row 2 to Row 3:

```
cellsOfFoundRow = FindXlCell(search_str, ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=3))
```

It's also posible to use 'ws.iter_cols(...' or any other function that will return a **squared_range**:

```
cellsOfFoundRow = FindXlCell(search_str, ws.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=3, max_col=3))
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice:4.3.3.2***