# Openpyxl, searching a value column wise.

Tags: openpyxl

Hello I am new to this site and python,
I am trying to use openpyxl and would like to know how to search a particular  value(getting user input) in column A (in about 2000 values) and printing the row number. With the row number i am trying to print the other values.

in the following example if user wants to look for 103 it should find it in this excel and should say the value of 103 is drt and item1 like that....

101  abc item1
102  ybx item1
103  drt item1

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wsnames=wb.sheetnames
sheet=wb['Sheet1']
valuestr = "103"
for row in ws.iter_cols:
  for cell in row:
     if (cell.value==valuestr):
       print (cell.row)
```

Please help...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If possible edit your question to clarify your problem description. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicat of [python Search a string in a column, and return another column value from that same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251246/python-search-a-string-in-a-column-and-return-another-column-value-from-that-sa/52369816#52369816)