# Write dictionary values to excel column B with corresponding dictionary keys in column A

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

I have a dictionary formatted similarly to the following (the actual dictionary is quite long):

```
myDictionary = {'Rent' : ['+100'], 'Other Income' : ['+10+20']}
```

I also have an excel file with the keys copied into column A.

What I am trying to do is iterate through the column of my excel workbook to find matching keys, and paste their corresponding values into column B of the same workbook.

Below is the snippet of code I have gotten closest with:

```
for row in destinationSheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        for key, value in myDictionary.items():
            if cell.value == key:
                for row in destinationSheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=2):
                    for cell in row:
                        cell.value = str(value)
```

The problem I am running into is that my code is placing the value of the final entry in my dictionary in every row in column B.  So my output looks like:

```
Column A         Column B
Rent            ['+10+20']
Other Income    ['+10+20']
```

I'd also like to strip off the brackets and apostrophes when I export to excel so that excel will retain the formula, but make the calculation, but I am trying to tackle my project one step at a time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm very new to this, so please be kind!

Comment: Hey, where are you getting the data you want to write from? How did it end up in the form `['+10+20']`? Wondering if we can save some steps here.

Comment: For example, do you want the formulas in column B to edited or would you be fine with the resulting values being written to column B (i.e. ="+10 + 20" or =30).

Comment: You need [search-a-string-in-a-column-and-return-another-column-value-from-that-sa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251246/python-search-a-string-in-a-column-and-return-another-column-value-from-that-sa/52369816#52369816) and [using-formulae](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae)

Comment: Use `zip` to loop over the rows and the dictionary.