# Get adjacent values from excel sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a sheet like this

```
        A       B       C                   D               E               F
1   
2                       Solider             Commando        Special
3
```

I want to search for the value Solider in this sheet.
Then Get all the other values adjacent to the value solider until i encounter a blank.

My try

```
for value in sheet.values:                                
    for item in value:                                    
        if type(item) is str and item.startswith('Solider'):
            print(item)
```

I am blank how to get the other values like Commando Special ...and i don't want to hard code the other values

Comment: Possible duplicate [search-a-string-in-a-column-and-return-another-column-value-from-that-sa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251246/python-search-a-string-in-a-column-and-return-another-column-value-from-that-sa/52369816#52369816)

Comment: Use `cell.offset()`