# How to extract a particular row value on inputting value of a particular row

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

I want to make a GUI program that inputs the value of a column
the program must go to the row where the inputted value is equal to the row value
and display the particular row value in a text box
but I am clueless on how to do this.

I tried using while loop to do it so it will search the whole excel file to check whether value of inputted data is equal to the data in the textbox but it did not go properly.

I am using python 3.7.0 using anaconda.

```
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl

a = Tk()
a.title('Return Book')
a.geometry('500x200')
heading = Label(a,text = 'Return Book')
heading.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
lab1 = Label(a,text = 'Enter Invoice Number:')
lab1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
inv_field = Entry(a)
inv_field.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
inv_field.get()
find = Button(a,text = 'Find',width = 4,command =a.destroy)
find.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


def find():
    ##extradiction
    ##location of excel file
    path = "E:\Library Management\issue.xlsx"
    # workbook object is created 
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)   
    sheet = wb.active 
    max_col = sheet.max_column 

    # Will print a particular row value 
    for i in range(1, max_col + 1): 
    cell_obj = sheet.cell(row = 2, column = i) 
    print(cell_obj.value, end = " ")



a.mainloop()
```

I expect the program to input the value of the invoice number and search the whole database for the number and print the row in the textbox.

Comment: Can you add an example data structure of your spreadsheet and the exact expected results from that example. That would help with understanding your exact needs. The data doesn't need to be anything real. Just some gibberish but in the right format.

Comment: Implement it like [Search a string in a column, and return another column value from that same row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369816/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you did not define the `textbox` in your code to show the search result.  Second you use `a.destroy` in `command` option of `find` button, it should be set to `find` function.  Also you use same name `find` for find button and find function.

Suggest to add a `Text` widget:

```
book_info = Text(a, width=40, height=5)
book_info.grid(...)
```

Then rename `find()` function to `find_book()` and add a new `update_text()` to show the search result as below:

```
def update_text(info):
    book_info.delete(1.0, 'end')
    book_info.insert('end', info)

def find_book():
    inv_no = inv_field.get()
    if inv_no:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('E:\Library Management\issues.xlsx')
        sheet = wb.active
        for row in sheet.rows:
            # assume invoice no is in column 1
            if row[0].value == inv_no:
                update_text('\n'.join(str(cell.value) if cell.value else '' for cell in row))
                return
        wb.close()
        update_text('Book not found')
```

Finally change the `command` option of `find` button to call the `find_book()` function:

```
find = Button(a, text='Find', command=find_book)
```

Comment: here i got a new one