# how to save the data entered in the textbox in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, text, openpyxl

i made a program that will input the invoice number and search the excel file(ref my previous question : [How to extract a particular row value on inputting value of a particular row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54113343/10652245)),

now i want to save the data fetched by the program into a new excel file using openpyxl,
but i dont know what is the solution to this,
i am using python 3.7.0.

my code is

```
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl

def update_text(info):
    book_info.delete(1.0, 'end')
    book_info.insert('end', info)

def find_book():
    inv_no = inv_field.get()
    if inv_no:
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('E:\Library Management\issue.xlsx')
            sheet = wb.active
            for row in sheet.rows:
                # assume invoice no is in column 1
                if row[0].value == inv_no:
                    update_text('\n'.join(str(cell.value) if cell.value else '' for cell in row))
                    return
            wb.close()
            update_text('Book not found')


a = Tk()
a.title('Return Book')
a.geometry('500x200')
heading = Label(a,text = 'Return Book')
heading.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
lab1 = Label(a,text = 'Enter Invoice Number:')
lab1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
inv_field = Entry(a)
inv_field.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
inv_field.get()
find = Button(a,text = 'Find',width = 4,command =find_book)
find.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
book_info = Text(a, width=40, height=5)
book_info.grid(row = 3 ,column = 1)

 a.mainloop()
```

how can i do this and how can i save the data displayed ,in a new excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another workbook and write the result into the active sheet.  Then save the workbook to file.  Below is an sample code:

```
outwb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = outwb.active
ws.append([1, 2, 3, 4])
outwb.save('result.xlsx')
outwb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it is done in openpyxl, but in xlwt it is .save(). Try running a print(help(wb)), should tell you all submethods on that object.

Comment: hmm, @Andrew Ray i am not sure about that

Comment: u saw my previous program , i gave link here go and see